# Why does the :focus-within pseudo-class not work with an iframe child?

Tags: css, iframe, css-selectors

When I tab through the buttons, the div turns green, but when I tab through the link inside the iframe, `:focus-within` stops functioning as expected and the div loses its green. This is the case on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

Is there a pure CSS way to get `:focus-within` to trigger on an element when an iframe descendent of that element has focus? If not, why this unexpected behavior from `focus-within`?

```css
div:focus-within {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>A</button>
    <iframe
        src="https://example.org"
        title="iframe Example 1"
        width="400"
        height="300">
    </iframe>
    <button>B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That answer offers a helpful javascript alternative, but my main concern is whether this can be done with CSS and if not, why not. I've edited the original question to reflect this.

Comment: The linked question also seeks a CSS only answer, I'll answer there